# Deploying React and Django on Heroku

Tags: node.js, django, reactjs, heroku

I've been hitting my head against this problem for a while and can't seem to figure it out. I'm trying to deploy a Django app to heroku where the front end uses react. I'm pretty new to react so it's possible I'm missing something fundamental here.

I have one heroku app right now that has two buildpacks (heroku/nodejs and heroku/python). To run the app locally I use `python manage.py runserver` along with `node server.js` on port 3000. I know Heroku only lets one port receive HTTP requests so I think the problem is there.

My main question is: To use Django and React on a Heroku app do I need to have two separate apps (one for django and one for react) or can I maintain only one app?

I've been searching through [this repository](https://github.com/SamSamskies/django-webpack-heroku-example) and it seems like only one app is used. However I can't see how the node server is working.

Thanks for any clarification or a push in the right direction! Let me know if I need to clarify my question.

Edit:
A couple other things I've tried:

1. Following [this tutorial](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/deploying-react-redux-to-heroku/)
2. Adding a `heroku-postbuild` script to my `package.json` file that starts the node server. This prevents the build process from continuing to start the django app though.
3. I came across [this blog post](https://engineering.heroku.com/blogs/2014-10-29-heroku-django-node/) too but it seems like I'm getting conflicting information on if the apps can be in the same Heroku app or must be different (like in the tutorial from #1).

Comment: I've implemented React and Django in just one application, using Django Rest Framework for API calls from the front end. As @taylorc93 said, you only need Node for server side rendering.

Comment: Hey did you figure this out? I still am having issues...

Answer (score 5):

Unless you plan on implementing server side rendering (not advisable if you're new to react), you only need one server.

What you're missing is a way to generate a javascript bundle that contains all of your react code.  Then, you can ship that bundle over to the client like you would any other HTML/CSS/JS file.

Try using a tool like [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/) to generate a javascript bundle.  If possible, put it in the `heroku-postbuild` step, if not, just generate the bundle before deploying the updates

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am currently using webpack along with `django-webpack-loader`. The bundles are generated but I don't believe I'm serving them correctly.

Comment: Hmmmm... Are you getting any error messages? Can you post your webpack config + relevant django settings (http://owaislone.org/blog/webpack-plus-reactjs-and-django/#settings-py)?

Comment: Do other static files get served? What if you just put a javascript file with `console.log("hello world")` and try to serve that in your HTML. Does it work? If not, the issue could be related to how Django serves static files.

Comment: If you end up doing server side rendering, you still only need one server. I wrote a blog post outlining this: http://blog.victorpontis.com/server-side-react